How to evaluate this Integral : $\Omega =\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \frac{\cos(2x)(1-\ln(\cos x))}{x^2 + (1-\ln(\cos x))^2}dx $
How to evaluate this Integral ?:
$$
\Omega =\int^{\pi/2}_{0}
\frac{\cos\left(2x\right)\left[1 - \ln\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)\right]}
{x^{2} + \left[1 - \ln\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)\right]^{2}}
\,{\rm d}x
$$
We have :
$$
\Re\left[{\frac{1}{1 + ix - \ln\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)}}\right] =
\frac{1 - \ln\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)}
{x^{2} + \left[1 - \ln\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)\right]^{2}}
$$
Therefore:
$$
\Omega =
\Re\left[{\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\frac{\cos\left(2x\right)}
{1 + ix - \ln\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)}}\right]
{\rm d}x
$$
How can I calculate this integral ?.
I need help with this.

Why was the question voted to close?

Numerically.  You get approximately $0.273968$.   I don't think there's a closed form.

$$ \begin{align}  \Omega &= \frac{1}{2} , \Re \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-u^{2}}{(1+u^{2})^{2}} \frac{\mathrm du}{\ln(1-iu)+1} \  &= \frac{1}{2} , \Re \ 2 \pi i \operatorname*{Res}_{z=i} \frac{1-z^{2}}{(1+z^{2})^{2}} \frac{1}{\ln(1-iz)+1} \ &= \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{(1+\ln 2)^{2}}.\end{align}$$

Nice . Thank you

Let $b=1-\ln \cos x$ and utilize  $\int_0^\infty \cos xt \ e^{-b t}dt=\frac b{x^2+b^2}$ to reexpress the integral as
\begin{align}
\Omega =&\int^{\pi/2}_{0} \frac{\cos2x\ (1-\ln\cos x)}{x^2 + (1-\ln \cos x)^2}dx \\
=& \int^{\pi/2}_0\int_0^\infty\cos2x \cos tx\ \cos^tx\ e^{-t}dt \ dx \\
=& \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t} }2\int^{\pi/2}_0 [\cos(t+2)x+ \cos(t-2)x] \cos^tx \ dx \ dt \\
\end{align}Evaluate the two inner integrals with $n=\pm 2$ as follows
\begin{align}
&\int^{\pi/2}_0 \cos[(t+n)x]\cos^tx \ dx \\
=&\ \Re \int^{\pi/2}_0 e^{i(t+n)t}\left(\frac{e^{i x}+e^{-i x}}2 \right)^t \ dx\\
 =&\ \Re\int^{\pi/2}_0 
\frac1{2^{t}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom tk e^{i(2k+n)x}\ dx=\frac{\pi t}{2^{t+1}}
\end{align}
which is for $n=-2$ and the integral with $n=2$ vanishes. Thus
$$\Omega= \frac\pi4\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}t}{2^{t}}\ dt
=\frac\pi{4(1+\ln2)^2}
$$

Let $\ln$ be the principal branch of the logarithm, and let $$\Omega(a)= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(2x) \, \frac{a- \ln \cos x}{x^{2}+ \left(a- \ln \cos x \right)^{2}} \, \mathrm dx.$$

For $a>0$ we have
$$\begin{align} \Omega(a) &=  \frac{1}{2} \int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} \cos(2x) \, \frac{a-\ln \cos x}{x^2 + \left(a-\ln \cos x\right)^2} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-u^{2}}{1+u^{2}} \frac{a+ \frac{1}{2}\ln(1+u^{2})}{\arctan^{2}(u)+ \left(a+ \frac{1}{2}\ln(1+u^{2}) \right)^{2}} \frac{du}{1+u^{2}} \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \, \Re \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-u^{2}}{(1+u^{2})^{2}} \frac{1}{a+\ln(1-iu)} \, \mathrm du \\&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-u^{2}}{(1+u^{2})^{2}} \frac{1}{a+\ln(1-iu)} \, \mathrm du. \end{align}$$
The branch cut for $\frac{1}{a+\ln(1-iz)}$ is in the lower half-plane.
And $\frac{1}{a+ \ln(1-iz)}$ has a pole at $z=i(e^{-a}-1)$, which is in the lower half-plane if $a>0$.
Therefore, integrating in the upper half-plane, we have
$$ \begin{align} \Omega(a) &= \frac{1}{2} \,2 \pi i   \operatorname*{Res}_{z=i}  \frac{1-z^{2}}{(1+z^{2})^{2}} \frac{1}{a+\ln(1-iz)} \\ &= \pi i  \lim_{z \to i} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz} \frac{1-z^{2}}{(z+i)^{2}} \frac{1}{a+\ln(1-iz)} \\ &= \pi i  \lim_{z \to i} \frac{\frac{-2z (z+i)^{2}-(1-z^{2})2(z+i)}{(z+i)^{4}} \left(a+\ln(1-iz) \right)- \frac{1-z^{2}}{(z+i)^{2}} \left(\frac{-i}{1-iz}\right)}{\left(a+\ln(1-iz) \right)^{2}} \\ &= \pi i  \, \frac{0- \frac{i}{4}}{(a+ \ln 2)^{2}} \\ &= \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{(a+ \ln 2)^{2}}. \end{align}$$

If $a=0$, we have
$$  \begin{align} \Omega(0) &= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(2x) \, \frac{-\ln \cos x}{x^2 + \ln^{2} (\cos x)} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \, \operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-u^{2}}{(1+u^{2})^{2}} \frac{\mathrm du}{\ln(1-iu)} \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \left(2 \pi i \operatorname*{Res}_{z=i} \frac{1-z^{2}}{(1+z^{2})^{2}} \frac{1}{\ln(1-iz)} + \pi i \operatorname*{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1-z^{2}}{(1+z^{2})^{2}} \frac{1}{\ln(1-iz)} \right) \\ &= \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{\ln^{2} 2} - \frac{\pi}{2}. \end{align}$$

And if $a <0$, we have
$$ \begin{align} \Omega(a) &= \frac{1}{2} 2 \pi i \left(\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i} \frac{1-z^{2}}{(1+z^{2})^{2}} \frac{1}{a+\ln(1-iz)} + \operatorname*{Res}_{z=i(e^{-a}-1)} \frac{1-z^{2}}{(1+z^{2})^{2}} \frac{1}{a+\ln(1-iz)} \right) \\ &= \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{\left(a + \ln 2 \right)^{2}} -  \pi e^{-a} \, \frac{1+(e^{-a}-1)^{2}}{\left(1-(e^{-a}-1)^{2}\right)^{2}}, \end{align}$$ with the special case
$$\Omega(-\ln 2) =  \lim_{a \to - \ln 2} \left( \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{\left(a + \ln 2 \right)^{2}} -  \pi e^{-a} \, \frac{1+(e^{-a}-1)^{2}}{\left(1-(e^{-a}-1)^{2}\right)^{2}} \right) = - \frac{11 \pi}{48}. $$
